# Adding item information to transaction object in arules

Tags: r, arules

I am using the `arules` package to find association rules in point-of-sale retail data. I am extracting transaction detail from a database, then placing in a `transaction` object. I'm new to `arules` and am trying to figure out how to populate the `itemInfo` data frame in the transaction object. Right now, I'm just bringing in the `transaction` and `item ID`s (both numeric), which provide little context. I would like to be able to add an item description, as well as product hierarchy levels.

Below is the process I'm using today:

1. Data comes through from the database in the below format:

   ```
   Transaction_ID     Item_ID
   --------------     ----------- 
   100                1
   100                2
   100                3
   101                2
   101                3
   102                1
   102                2
   ```
2. To create the `transaction` object, I'm using the below command, as described in the `arules` documentation:

   ```
   txdata <- as(split(txdata[, "Item_ID"], txdata[, "Transaction_ID"]), "transactions")
   ```

   Note: I've found that I need to have a numeric value for the `Item_ID`, otherwise I run into major performance issues using a string (due to poor performance of split when using factored strings).
3. Create and view the association rules

   ```
   rules <- apriori(txdata, parameter = list(support=0.00015, confidence=0.5))
   inspect(head((sort(rules, by="confidence")), n=5))
   ```

When the rules come back, they are listed by `Item_ID`, which is not helpful to me. I want to be able to display them by the `ID` and/or description. Also, would like to take advantage of the aggregation features built into the `arules` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the names of items using itemInfo. Here is an example:

```
R> df <- data.frame(
   TID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3), 
   item=c("a","b","a","b","c", "b")
 )
R> trans <- as(split(df[,"item"], df[,"TID"]), "transactions")

### this is how you replace item labels and set a hierachy (here level1)
R> myLabels <- c("milk", "butter", "beer")
R> myLevel1 <- c("dairy", "dairy", "beverage")
R> itemInfo(trans) <- data.frame(labels = myLabels, level1 = myLevel1)

R> inspect(trans)
     items    transactionID
  1 {milk,                
     butter}             1
  2 {milk,                
     butter,              
     beer}               2
  3 {butter}             3

 ### now you can use aggregate()
 R> inspect(aggregate(trans, itemInfo(trans)[["level1"]]))
     items      transactionID
  1 {dairy}                1
  2 {beverage,              
     dairy}                2
  3 {dairy}                3
```

You can find more info using `class? transactions` and `? aggregate`.

Hope this helps,
Michael

Comment: This is very helpful -- thank you. This may seem like a basic question, but how do I know the order in which to apply the labels? My data set has thousands of items, so I want to be sure I'm listing the labels in the correct order? Is it just in order of the first occurrence in the data set?

Comment: It looks like I can just pull the data from the `itemInfo` slot in the transaction object, using `trans@itemInfo`, then assign the labels in the order shown there.

Comment: That is right, you can take the itemInfo and then use match to get the labels in the right order.

Comment: When I use aggregate for rules and inspect it, it doesn't show support/confidence etc., any reason why  data("Groceries")


## Aggregate rules
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(supp=0.005, conf=0.5))
inspect(rules)
aggrules<-aggregate(rules, level1)
inspect(aggrules)

Comment: @usct01: the reason is that supp/conf/lift of the aggregated rules cannot be calculated from the measures for the original rules. You can aggregate the data and then use `interestMeasures` to calculate the measures for your aggregated rules. Alternatively, you could just aggregate the transactions first and then create rules. These will have the measures.