# Add extended transaction information to arules transactions object

Tags: r, arules

I have a data frame that I’m trying to coerce into a transactions object for analysis using the `arules` package. Here is a reproducible example for my question:

```
df <- data.frame(
  case_number = c("1001", "1001", "1002", "1002", "1003"),
  date = as.Date(c("2016-04-19", "2016-04-21", "2016-05-21", "2016-05-25", 
    "2016-06-14")),
  happy = factor(c("Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No")),
  food = ordered(
    c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1),
    levels = c(1, 2, 3),
    labels = c("A lot", "Some", "None")
  ),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df

  case_number       date happy  food
1        1001 2016-04-19   Yes A lot
2        1001 2016-04-21    No  Some
3        1002 2016-05-21   Yes A lot
4        1002 2016-05-25    No  None
5        1003 2016-06-14    No A lot
```

I have no trouble coercing if I drop case_numer and date. However, in the [introduction to arules](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arules/vignettes/arules.pdf), example 1, a summary of the Epub transactions object includes the following:

```
includes extended transaction information - examples:
      transactionID           TimeStamp
10792  session_4795 2003-01-01 19:59:00
10793  session_4797 2003-01-02 06:46:01
10794  session_479a 2003-01-02 09:50:38
```

You can recreate this yourself using the following code:

```
library(arules)
data(Epub)
summary(Epub)
```

My question is, how do I add `case_number` and `date` as *extended transaction information* as above. I’ve looked through the arules documentation and this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952011/adding-item-information-to-transaction-object-in-arules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transaction information can be accessed with the methods `transactionInfo` (see `? transactions`). It contains a data.frame with one row per transactions.